# Why is Rails' ERB rendering output from this template code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm using Rails 3.0.3, and the following template (with a .html.erb extension):

```
<% "one"; "two"; capture do %>
    Three
<% end %>
```

Is rendering as:

```
one
```

Why is this? It doesn't seem like it should render anything, since I didn't use <%=

EDIT

Since there seems to be some confusion, here is a reproduction that more closely resembles the actual template code that I'm debugging:

```
<% my_string = "" %>
<% my_string << capture do %>
    Hello
<% end %>
<%= my_string %>
```

This is rendering as:

```
    Hello    Hello
```

Because for some reason, the captured output is being appended to my_string AND being rendered, instead of just the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the rails [capture helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-capture) but your syntax is wrong. I don't know why it's printing out `one`. In rails 3.4 it doesn't print out anything.

Here's the right way to use it

```
<% @number = capture do %>
   three
<% end %>

this is some html and here is my <%= @number %>
```

The html that will be rendered is

```
this is some html and here is my three
```

Since your syntax is wrong I wouldn't worry about why "one" is showing up. Instead I'd focus more on using the capture helper correctly.

---

**Edit:**

Your second (edited) example is not the same as your first one. Here it is with line numbers and a slight change to the last line so you can see what's going on.

```
1. <% my_string = "" %>
2. <% my_string << capture do %>
3.     Hello
4. <% end %>
5. before <%= my_string %> after
```

The result is `Hello before Hello after`. So line 3 is being rendered, then line 5 is being rendered with `my_string` containing the value `Hello`.

If you change it to this

```
 <% my_string = "" %>
 <% my_string = capture do %>  <!-- changed << to = -->
     Hello
 <% end %>
 before <%= my_string %> after
```

Then the result is `before Hello after`.

So what does this all mean? When you use `<<` it's screwing up the `capture` method and it's rendering stuff that's inside the capture block even though normally you don't expect it to.

Basically, you can't do what you're trying to do here, at least not with your current syntax.

Comment: Yeah, I am actually appending the return value of capture to another string, but I omitted that detail in order to simplify my example.

Comment: I updated my original post with a better example. And yes, I've tried both.

Comment: @Daniel ok, think I figured it out

Comment: Hmm okay, thanks. Though it's unfortunate, because in my particular case I need to use <<, so I guess I'll have to rework some other stuff.

Comment: @Daniel You could just assign the `capture` to a variable then append to it  later. Also would appreciate marked answer if this answered your question.